# Python server can't access files with escaped characters in the URL

Tags: python

I have a python server for mp3 streaming. Using Twisted Matrix library.

If I try to access the file `a.mp3` it works normally.

But this file, for example `衝.mp3` doesn't work, it says "File not found".

This file name as URL escaped is `%E8%A1%9D.mp3` but it can't access it.

If I try to access it using unicode instead of the symbol, like this `\u885d.mp3` it still says "File not found".

Here is the code, notice that I had to put `request.path = request.path.replace('%20', ' ')` because that's the only way it can access a file that has spaces in the path. That shouldn't be the normal behaviour I believe.

```
class playMP3(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        this=urlparse.urlparse(request.path)#scheme,netloc,path,query
        root,ext=os.path.splitext(this.path)
        filename=os.path.basename(request.path)
        fileFolder=request.path.replace(filename,"")
        self.serverRoot=os.getcwd()
        print (request.path)
        if ext==".mp3":
        request.path = request.path.replace('%20', ' ')
            thisFile=File(self.serverRoot+request.path)
            return File.render_GET(thisFile,request)

resource = playMP3()
factory = Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(8880, factory)
reactor.run()
```

I also tried to put `request.path = urllib.unquote(request.path)` but instead of decoding it to `衝.mp3` it becomes `ÞíØ.mp3`. Weird.

Comment: This is python 2? Python 3 has better unicode support. What is `sys.stdout.encoding`? Here is my guess: The escaped sequence is unquoted into 3 bytes which happen to render to `ÞíØ` in your code page. Try `urllib.unquote(request.path).decode('utf-8')`. What exactly did you try with the unicode escape? Something like `open(u"\u885d.mp3")` (note the 'u' at the front)? What is `sys.getdefaultencoding()` and `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`? They may help show your environment.

Comment: And consider reimplementing in python 3. Its been out for a decade and has much better language support.

Comment: Solved, thank you so much. I switched to python 3, got the same error but it worked 100% after I put `urllib.parse.unquote(request.path).encode('utf-8')` like you said (just encode instead of decode). All good now. Thank you again, you're awesome.

Comment: Interesting. In python 3, `urllib.parse.unquote` does the decode for you. I'm not sure why you needed the encode later. Was that for an OS call? Anyway, glad it worked!